# Show value on title from clicked item with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am working on a project and facing a problem. It's a jQuery problem and I am not good in jQuery. I want when someone clicked on list item(`<ul id="res-menu-filters"><li></li></ul>`) the value will change on h3(`<h3 id="menu-title-layout-text">Change Value</h3>`) tag with the value of div#menu-extend-title (`<div id="menu-extend-title">Breakfast</div>`).

I tried a jQuery but it's not working.

Below is my html code and jQuery code.

How should i make this work?

Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="menu-title-layout-change">
 <h3 id="menu-title-layout-text">Breakfast</h3>
</div>


<ul id="res-menu-filters">
  <li class="filter">Category 1
    <div id="menu-extend-title">
     Breakfast
    </div>
 </li>
 <li class="filter">Category 2
   <div id="menu-extend-title">
     Launch
   </div>
 </li>
 <li class="filter">Category 3
   <div id="menu-extend-title">
     Dinner
   </div>
 </li>
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery('#restaurant-menu-content-tab').on('click', '#res-menu-filters li', function(e)
{
    var value = jQuery('#menu-extend-title').text();

    jQuery('#menu-title-layout-text').text(value);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique** - use class instead of ID for repeated elements

Comment: Oh yeah... i was totally forgot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) of an element must be unique**, so need to use class to group similar elements, also in the click handler you need to find the `title` element which is a descendant of the clicked `li`

```js
jQuery('#restaurant-menu-content-tab').on('click', '#res-menu-filters li', function(e) {
  var value = jQuery(this).find('.menu-extend-title').text();
  jQuery('#menu-title-layout-text').text(value);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="restaurant-menu-content-tab">
  <div class="menu-title-layout-change">
    <h3 id="menu-title-layout-text">Breakfast</h3>
  </div>
  <ul id="res-menu-filters">
    <li class="filter">Category 1
      <div class="menu-extend-title">Breakfast</div>
    </li>
    <li class="filter">Category 2
      <div class="menu-extend-title">Launch</div>
    </li>
    <li class="filter">Category 3
      <div class="menu-extend-title">Dinner</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use common class instead if you used duplicated ids

```
<ul id="res-menu-filters">
 <li class="filter">Category 1
    <div class="menu-extend-title">
     Breakfast
    </div>
 </li>
 <li class="filter">Category 2
   <div class="menu-extend-title">
     Launch
   </div>
 </li>
 <li class="filter">Category 3
   <div class="menu-extend-title">
     Dinner
   </div>
 </li>
```

jquery

```
jQuery('#restaurant-menu-content-tab').on('click', '#res-menu-filters li', function(e){
    var value = jQuery(this).find('.menu-extend-title').text();
    jQuery('#menu-title-layout-text').text(value);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of the following issues:

1. HTML `menu-extend-title` is an ID. It should be unique for elements.
2. Change `menu-extend-title` to class and use `.menu-extend-title`.
3. Use the following code:

   ```
   <li class="filter">Category 1
      <div class="menu-extend-title">
       Breakfast
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="filter">Category 2
     <div class="menu-extend-title">
       Launch
     </div>
   </li>
   <li class="filter">Category 3
     <div class="menu-extend-title">
       Dinner
     </div>
   </li>

   jQuery('#restaurant-menu-content-tab').on('click', '#res-menu-filters li', function(e) {
     var value = jQuery('.menu-extend-title', this).text();
     jQuery(this).find('div').text(value);
     return false;
   });
   ```

Comment: Oh yeah.... ID should be unique.. This was out of my mind. I am really sorry for that. Now it works. But it shows all the value containing the class .menu-extend-title . I just want to show only one value which one is clicked.

Comment: @Blackboy Updated the answer with the contextual selector. Refresh and check.

Answer (score 0):

As arun pointed out, IDs should be unique. You should rather use classname. also you can use current li context to get the required div in it using current clicked context and find selector:

```
 jQuery('#restaurant-menu-content-tab').on('click', '#res-menu-filters li', function(e){      
  var value = jQuery(this).find('div').text();
  jQuery('#menu-title-layout-text').text(value);
  return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

here a better html code:

```
<div class="menu-title-layout-change">
 <h3 class="menu-title-layout-text">Breakfast</h3>
</div>


<ul class="res-menu-filters">
  <li class="filter">Category 1
    <div class="menu-extend-title">
     Breakfast
    </div>
 </li>
 <li class="filter">Category 2
   <div class="menu-extend-title">
     Launch
   </div>
 </li>
 <li class="filter">Category 3
   <div class="menu-extend-title">
     Dinner
   </div>
 </li>
```

Make sure your html id's are unique!
And this jquery:

```
 $(document).on('click','.res-menu-filters',function(){
  $('.menu-title-layout-text').text($(this).find('.menu-extend-title').text());
 })
```